# Function running without being called

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have a function that I got from a company spreadsheet to calculate rescission dates, I added the sheet as another sheet in my workbook to avoid opening another workbook when I need to use this functionality. The odd thing that is happening is that this function is being executed by my other procedures without me calling the function. I have stepped through many times but don't see why this function is being called. Any thoughts?

```
Function sixdayworkweek(rngIn As Range, lngDays As Long, rngHolidays As Range)
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngStartDate As Long, lngNextDay As Long, lngWorkDayCount As Long
Dim lngIncr As Long, lngC As Long
Application.Volatile
lngStartDate = CLng(rngIn.Value)
lngNextDay = lngStartDate
Do
  lngNextDay = lngNextDay + 1
  lngIncr = 1
If Weekday(lngNextDay, vbSunday) = 1 Then
  ' if day is Sunday, don't count it as a workday
  lngIncr = 0
Else
  For Each rngCell In rngHolidays
    ' if day is Holiday, don't count it as a workday
    If lngNextDay = CLng(rngCell.Value) Then
      lngIncr = 0
      Exit For
    End If
  Next rngCell
End If
' increment day by 1 or 0 if a Sunday or Holiday
lngWorkDayCount = lngWorkDayCount + lngIncr
Loop Until lngWorkDayCount = lngDays
sixdayworkweek = CDate(lngNextDay)
End Function
```

Comment: if the function is used in a cell somewhere, it will be called every time a re-calc occurs. Do a search for the function in your worksheets.

Comment: Thanks @ScottHoltzman but I am not suing on the actual sheet I am on, it is being used in another sheet on the same workbook. Is there a way to have it launch only when I am in that particular sheet?

Comment: No, but you can turn calcs off while you step through if that is an option.

Comment: Ok I’ll try it, can you tell me what the code is for turning calcs off?

Comment: You can easily find by google, but it's `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`